# need help to take phpMyAdmin database's backup

Tags: php, backup

i want to  backup my database from php file...
i am using phpMyAdmin as back end. i want to create excel file from that data base is it possible? yes then how? give me some suggestion on it thanks in advance...
**my one more querty is**:
if i am running this php code then when it store that file..? i've checked into the phpMyAdmin bt that was not inside that the code is as below

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';
$tableName  = 'mypet';
$backupFile = 'backup/mypet.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $login_master";
$result = mysql_query($query);

include 'closedb.php';
?>
```

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1):

New backup link :
Mysqli :  https://www.dropbox.com/s/s9qmvj7um4h5tdx/backup.php?dl=0 
Mysql :https://www.dropbox.com/s/n14p9uf9wc09ow0/index.php?dl=0

**Put this file in your WWW folder and just run it dont panic if error occured but you database is backuped in www folder**

```
    /* backup the db OR just a table */
    function backup_tables($host,$user,$pass,$name,$tables = '*')
    {

        $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
        mysql_select_db($name,$link);

        //get all of the tables
        if($tables == '*')
        {
            $tables = array();
            $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
            {
                $tables[] = $row[0];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(',',$tables);
        }

        //cycle through
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

            $return.'='. 'DROP TABLE '.$table.';';
            $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
            $return.= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) 
            {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    $return.= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';
                    for($j=0; $j<$num_fields; $j++) 
                    {
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                        if (isset($row[$j])) { $return.= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ; } else { $return.= '""'; }
                        if ($j<($num_fields-1)) { $return.= ','; }
                    }
                    $return.= ");\n";
                }
            }
            $return.="\n\n\n";
        }

        //save file

        $handle = fopen('store-'.date("Y-m-d-H-i-s").'-'.(implode(',',$tables)).'.sql','w+');
        fwrite($handle,$return);
        fclose($handle);
    }
header("http://localhost/store/");
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy.

1. On the phpmyadmin graphic interface, select the database you want to save.
2. Click on the `export` tab at the top.
3. Select "excel" from the box you'll find on the right.
4. Click `go` at the bottom.

Done.

Comment: yes that is a way but i want to do this kind of thing using php

Comment: Then, here is the code you need: http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

Answer (score 0):

Once you have selected your database, you should click on "Export" tab. You  will be shown a page with a number of options (which tables to export, the name of the export file, the type of file, whether excel or sql or whatever...).

Anyway, I suggest to use the command line if possible.